# Is that possible to parallel resolve list from two+ dns servers?

Tags: python, dnspython

I am total new with python, and to be honest, programming at all. I made my first script for resolving list of domains with Google help and some luck I guess.

List of domains contains about 100 000 domains, and I have to optimize time for complete this task, because it will repeating task, and now it need about two hour to do it. I can split list and run each script separately, but if possible to set up 2 or more DNS servers and parallel resolving from them it will great.
Or maybe there is more methods to optimize running time?

I had read docs for dnspython, but its too complex for my python skill level (which is ~0).

```
import socket
import dns.resolver

w = open ('/home/dalt/pyth/resolved.txt', "w")
x = open ('/home/dalt/pyth/not_resolved.txt', "w")
with open('/home/dalt/pyth/domains2.txt') as f:
    my_list = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]

resolver = dns.resolver.Resolver()
resolver.nameservers=[socket.gethostbyname('212.xxx.xxx.134')]

for domain in my_list:
    try:
        q = resolver.query(domain, 'A')
        for ipval in q:
            print(ipval, file=w)
    except dns.resolver.NXDOMAIN:
            print(domain, 'NXDOMAIN', file=x)
    except dns.resolver.NoNameservers:
        print(domain, 'NoNameservers',file=x)
    except dns.resolver.NoAnswer:
        print(domain, 'NoAnswer',file=x)
    except dns.name.BadEscape:
        print(domain, 'BadEscape',file=x)

f.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not very experienced with networking but I would guess most of the execution time of your script comes from communication with the DNS server, which means that your CPU is mostly just waiting for data, which means that you should be able to optimize the task by the use of multiple threads.

It is the easiest to use a `ThreadPool`:

```py
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
import socket

import dns.resolver

my_list = [
    "www.google.com",
    "www.facebook.com",
    "doesnt.exist",
]

resolver = dns.resolver.Resolver()
resolver.nameservers=[
    socket.gethostbyname("8.8.4.4"),
    socket.gethostbyname("8.8.8.8"),
]

w = open("resolved.txt", "w")
x = open("not_resolved.txt", "w")

def resolve(domain):
    try:
        q = resolver.query(domain, "A")
        for ipval in q:
            print(domain, ipval, file=w)
    except dns.resolver.NXDOMAIN:
        print(domain, "NXDOMAIN", file=x)
    except dns.resolver.NoNameservers:
        print(domain, "NoNameservers", file=x)
    except dns.resolver.NoAnswer:
        print(domain, "NoAnswer", file=x)
    except dns.name.BadEscape:
        print(domain, "BadEscape", file=x)

pool = ThreadPool(processes=10)  # increasing this number may speed things up
results = pool.map(resolve, my_list)

w.close()
x.close()
```

Results:

```
$ cat not_resolved.txt
doesnt.exist NXDOMAIN
$ cat resolved.txt
www.google.com 172.217.20.196
www.facebook.com 31.13.81.36
```

The above code doesn't attempt to distribute the list of domains among the available DNS servers, unless the `dnspython` package does it under the hood. But I would expect that even a single DNS server will respond really quickly to concurrent queries, because it probably uses multiple threads itself.

Comment: I got "AttributeError: 'Resolver' object has no attribute 'resolve'" when tried to run your code :(

Comment: Replaced to q = resolver.query(domain, "A") and its run. On linux python forced me to replace query to resolve, on freebsd - otherwise. Too complex for me.

Comment: Oops sorry for that, when I ran your code I got a deprecation warning telling me to use `resolve` instead, so I just did that. But I guess you're using an older version of the library. I'll edit the answer to use the original.

Comment: Yes, i already did it, thx. Now will try it for real task with big list.

Comment: Thanks you very much, its solved my problem. I had set 60 processes, and it finished resolving 226k domains in 8 minuts. I runned it directly on my DNS server and it got only 30-50% CPU load both bind+python.

Comment: I only dont understand this line "results = pool.map(resolve, my_list)" can you explain it in simple terms?

Comment: `pool.map` is pretty much like the built-in higher order function `map` which *maps* a function to a collection, so `x = map(fun, stuff)` is equivalent to `x = (fun(item) for item in stuff)`. `x` in this case contains the results of calling `fun` on elements of `stuff`. `pool.map` does the same thing but it uses the thread pool to execute every instance of the function call in a separate thread, which is good for us because the threads can run concurrently.

Comment: The `results = ` part here is actually redundant because we're not using it. It is the new collection (`x` from the above example), i.e. the list of results of the function calls, in this case just a lot of `None` objects, because `resolve` doesn't return anything (actually it implicitly returns `None`).

Comment: Thx. I guess i understand, as i hope.